# MongoDB aggregation $lookup to parent array field with pipeline syntax and _id as string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following collections in my MongoDB (v.4.4):

`guilds`:

```js
{
 _id: String,
 members: [{ _id String, rank: number },{ _id String, rank: number }...]
}
```

and `characters`:

```js
{
  _id: String,
  many_other: 'fields'
}
```

And I'd like to join with the `$lookup` pipeline syntax `guild.members <= characters` by `_id` field.

> *I don't use Mongo build-in `OjbectIds` as `_id`, I overwrite it with strings in both collections. As I heard, there is a bit different behaviour with `$lookup` with strings as `_id` in pipelines. So make sure, that you knew about it, before answering.*

The expected result that I want is simple, I'd like to save rank from the original document, and also add any other field from `$lookup` it:

```js
{
  _id: String // (guild)
  members: [
    {
      _id: String, // (characters)
      rank: number,
      many_other: '...fields from characters'
    },
    {
      _id: String, // (characters)
      rank: number,
      many_other: '...fields from characters'
    }, ...
]
```

[Mongo Playground example: **avaliable**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8hbrNVWe9TA)

What have I tried:

Various queries, like:

```js
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "characters",
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: { $eq: [ { $toString :"$members._id" }, { $toString : "$$character_id" } ] }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "guild_members"
        },
      }
```

With converting ID's to string, with `let` stages variables, and using `$map` operator. But I still far away from the required result.

> *There is also another problem, which is some relevance to the question, but not related to queries itself*

As you may see, the `characters` collection has `many other fields`. Some of them are pretty heavy, (because guilds can have up to 500 members) which making the result document  >16 MB (MongoDB threshold limit) which gives an error. Since, as far as I know, we could not pick fields from `joined` documents, it will be much better to exclude it right after the `$lookup` stage or something like that. Any advice about it will be pretty welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup with pipeline is not required, when you pass `members._id` as localField,

- `$lookup` with characters and pass `members._id` as localField
- `$map` to iterate loop of `members` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `members_guid` and get matching member
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first matching element from above filter
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current fields with above filtered object of member

```
db.guilds.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "characters",
      localField: "members._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "members_guid"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      members: {
        $map: {
          input: "$members",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$m",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$members_guid",
                      cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$m._id"] }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yhpws7R9TE2)

Comment: The query is fine, I also have another one as well, the problem is a bit wider. What is want to erase/exclude some fields from the joined document (`characters`) before or immediately after the `$lookup` stage? For example (`characters.pets`). In that case, I could simple remove them in the `$project` stage, inside `$map`. am I correct here?

Comment: yes you can but it is better if you remove in adding extra project stage, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GJRn0qRQBY_)

Answer (score 2):

I take the @turivishal answer since the old-style-native aggregation is much easier to understand than `pipeline` syntax. But if someone is interested, my old part of aggregation, which I used a while ago.

```js
db.guilds.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "characters",
      let: {
        members: "$members"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$members._id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            rank: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$$members",
                initialValue: null,
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$_id"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$this.rank",
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "members"
    },
    
  }
])
```